# jQuery - What is the good way to implement continouns ranking

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have 4 input fields now:

```
<table>
<tr><th></th><th>Factor 1</th></tr>
<tr><td>Company A</td><td><input type="text" name="text1" id="text1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Company B</td><td><input type="text" name="text2" id="text2"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Company C</td><td><input type="text" name="text3" id="text3"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Company D</td><td><input type="text" name="text4" id="text4"></td></tr>
</table>
```

The inputs are integer from 1 to 4 uniquely in each input field. It is like a ranking for which **Company** is the best for this **Factor**, and which is the second and so on.

For example:

- When we input `1`, `3`, we alert `2` is missing in the ranking.
- When we input `1`, `2`, `4`, then we alert `3` is missing.

Inputs are not required, but when there are inputs, the sequence must from 1 to 4.

Here is the code I tried.

```
function checkMissingRank(object){
  object.change(function() {
    var max = 0;
    var actSum = 0;
    var rows = object.length;

    for(var i=1 ; i<=rows ; i++){
        if($('#text'+i+'').val() != ""){
            var actVal = parseInt($('#text'+i+'').val());
            //alert("actVal: "+actVal);
            actSum = actSum + actVal;
            if(actVal>max){
                max=actVal;
                //alert("max: "+ max);
            }
        }
    }
    //alert("actSum: "+ actSum);

    totalSum = ((1+max)*max)/2;
    //alert("totalSum: "+ totalSum);

    var missVal = totalSum - actSum;
    //alert("missVal "+ missVal);

    if(missVal != 0){
        alert("Ranking "+missVal+" is missing.");
    }
  });
}
checkMissingRank($('input[name^="text"]'));
```

It is working fine when just one Value missing (1 missing from 1 ,2 ,3, 4). But when 1, 2 both missing, it return 3 is missing which is the sum of 1 and 2. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your question stil not clear. Is 4 input text must be filled all?

Comment: did you a look at `required` attribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp . It does what you are looking for

Comment: Please try to be a bit more specific, in your examples it isn't clear where the user has entered (or missed) a value. Maybe it helps if you explain the real requirement behind this, I have a hard time to imagines that a form asks for the values 1 to 4 in 4 input fields.

Comment: Besides that: Have you written any code so far that you could share?

Comment: @reto I updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: As you noticed yourself, a sum based approach won't work. The answers give working solutions, please be very specific about why these approaches won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
<input type="text" name="text2" id="text2">
<input type="text" name="text3" id="text3">
<input type="text" name="text4" id="text4">
<input type="button" id="btnTest">
```

and Jquery:

```
$("#btnTest").click(function() {
      $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
        var msg = $(this).prop("id");
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
          switch (msg) {
            case ("text1"):
              alert('miss 1');
              break;
            case ("text2"):
              alert('miss 2');
              break;
            case ("text3"):
              alert('miss 3');
              break;
            case ("text4"):
              alert('miss 4');
              break;
          }
        }

      })
    });
```

Fiddle Sample https://jsfiddle.net/shree/5ucxau2n/1/

I create a sample on button click.Hope its help.

Comment: Sorry, I think I explained my problem in a wrong way. Please see my updates.

Answer (score 0):

This alerts each input that is missing.

```js
$(function(){
  $("button").on("click", function(){
    $("input").each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == ""){
        alert($(this).attr("id")  + " is missing");
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
  <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2">
  <input type="text" name="text3" id="text3">
  <input type="text" name="text4" id="text4">
</form>
<button>Enter</button>
```

This is if you just want a list of all the input elements that are missing. Only one alert box:

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  var str = ""
  $("input").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ""){
      str += $(this).attr("id") + " and "

    }
  })
  alert(str  + " is missing");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" placeholder = "type 1">
  <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" placeholder = "type 2">
  <input type="text" name="text3" id="text3" placeholder = "type 3">
  <input type="text" name="text4" id="text4" placeholder = "type 4">
</form>
<button>Enter</button>
```

Any Questions? let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I think I explained my problem in a wrong way. Please see my updates.